# Creating new pandas DataFrame from existing DataFrame and index

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
  a b
A 1 0
B 0 1
```

and I have an array ["A","B","C"].

From these, I want to create a new DataFrame like this:

```
  a   b
A 1   0
B 0   1
C NaN NaN
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you're after (setting aside weird duplicated-index cases), one way is to use `loc` to index into your frame:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {'A': 1, 'B': 0}, 'b': {'A': 0, 'B': 1}})
>>> arr = ["A", "B", "C"]
>>> df
   a  b
A  1  0
B  0  1
>>> df.loc[arr]
    a   b
A   1   0
B   0   1
C NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an DataFrame with only index=['C'] and concat:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {'A': 1, 'B': 0}, 'b': {'A': 0, 'B': 1}}
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(index=['C'])])
```