# Create new Pandas DataFrame using Index labels (iloc ERROR: Flexible Type)

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, error-handling, dataframe

This is pretty much exactly what I was trying to do: [Creating new pandas DataFrame from existing DataFrame and index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873190/creating-new-pandas-dataframe-from-existing-dataframe-and-index)

Instead of having index numbers, I have labels that I'm trying to Index by...

Pseudocode:

```
want_these_indices = ['A1BG',
 'A4GALT',
 'AAAS',
 'AADAT',
 'AAK1',
 'AAMP',
 'AANAT',
 'AARS',...]

sorted(DF.index)
['A1BG',
 'A4GALT',
 'AAAS',
 'AACS',
 'AADAT',
 'AAGAB',
 'AAK1',
 'AAMP',
 'AANAT',
 'AARS',
 'AARS2',...]
```

but when I `DF2 = DF.iloc[want_these_indices]`  I get 
`TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type`  I've even tried `DF.iloc[want_these_indices,:]`

I thought that it may be the fact that some of the indices were floats or something but they are all strings.  In both `DF.index` and `want_these_indices`

Comment: `df.iloc` is strictly integer-based indexing. Do you mean to use `df.loc` instead?

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that was an option.  All the examples i've ever seen used iloc.  Can you put this as an answer so I can mark it correct? It works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas has different index selection mechanisms, some of which use integers for positions, and others use labels. You have a string based index and thus need to use an indexer that is not a positional one. More specifically, `df.iloc` is strictly integer-based indexing. You will want to use `df.loc` instead.

Comment: why does this error pop up sometimes? `ValueError: cannot set an array element with a sequence` when all the labels are in DataFrame . `X = X.loc[index_labels]` yields the error when the index value is a tuple?

Comment: Not sure. Tuple indexing should be kosher, but you may want to use `pd.IndexSlice` instead--they are friendlier for many cases of multi-indices.